# Remove Outlook 2007 Calendar from Calendars List

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2007, calendar

In our company, we use personal folders with Outlook 2007 and make it the default method of downloading messages to keep our mailbox size on the server side small.
Under calendar view, i see both calendars, my personal folder one and my server one.
How can I remove from the list of calendars my server one since I do not use that one and it only creates confusion and problems such as adding entries onto that one instead of the other or disabling one and not getting alarms?

I tried googling on it and read there is a utility to do that but couldn't find the name of it.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Would "Go" -> "Folder List" and removing of the calender from the folder list work?

Comment: nope, the delete option for the server side calendar is grayed out.